# C# SMO - Scripting Table Data to File. Throwing Error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, smo

I'm trying to create a backup of the data contained within my database before I re-create the tables. I've got so far as to connect to the server and create the file to store the SQL. The problem is its throwing an error on the last line.

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

I've been at this project all day so might be missing something that a fresh pair of eyes would help with.

Here's the code:

```
public void scriptTables()
    {
        string folder = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Scripts/SQLScripts/");

        Server myServer = new Server(".\\SQLEXPRESS");
        Database CMSDB = myServer.Databases["CMSDB"];

        Scripter script = new Scripter(myServer);
        ScriptingOptions so = new ScriptingOptions();
        so.ScriptData = true;
        so.ScriptSchema = true;
        so.ScriptDrops = false;

        foreach (Table table in CMSDB.Tables)
        {
            string tables = table.ToString();
            string filename = folder + table + ".sql";
            FileStream fs = File.Create(filename);
            so.FileName = filename;

            CMSDB.Tables[tables].EnumScript(so);
        }
    }
}
```

Some background to what I'm doing:

I want to pull the data that already exists in the DB and then change the entity models. When the application restarts the EF framework will drop and re-create the database at which point I'll re-enter the data that was previously there. Not too sure if the whole process will work out but this will have to do until they release the migration feature in EF.

Hope someone can help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is probably table.ToString(). Try using table.Name instead.

Comment: Yes that was it, got rid of that error and now another one :) Script failed for Table 'dbo.aspnet_Applications'. I'll keep at it. Thanks for seeing what I didn't

Comment: Glad I could help :) I left you a suggestion on my other answer - seems like it should meet your needs.

Comment: Looks like it might, I've thought out this plan and I think it'll work so will give it another bit of work before abandoning it. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

How are you planning on putting the data back? I have yet to use EF code first, and I am quite comfortable in SQL server, so I would definitely settle on a solution using either SSMS or good ol T-SQL **if I were in your shoes.**

What is the nature of the schema changes you are making? Are you dropping columns, rearranging columns, or something more complex? If you are dropping columns, those columns can be dropped in T-SQL rather trivially. If you are rearranging columns, then you will have to push the data to a temp (or standard/permanent) table, make your changes, then script the changes back. This is fairly easy to do as well. If you expand on your needs, perhaps someone can help you come to a simple sql solution.

Comment: Part of the Initializer which is run in Global.asax, namely "Start_Application", allows you to run an SQL script on the database once it has been created. When I restart the app, EF will notice that the model is different from the DB and drop and recreate. It is something more complex, basically the system has the option to plugin features which have their own tables, when installing the plugin I'll update the model, restart the app and then run my scripts to re-populate the tables that were already there. Its messy, I know but can't think of another way to achieve what I want

Comment: A quick and dirty way of persisting your current tables would be to script them either to another database on the same server, or to a global temp table. You can do that like: select * into ##mytemp from mytable If you do this, know that global temp tables are dropped after the session that created them ends and no other sessions are referencing them

Comment: +1 whole schema change can be done by T-SQL and data can be "saved" into table-variables or temporary-tables.

Comment: Thanks, I may try these two tomorrow with a fresh head. For the moment jlnorsworthy spotted what was causing this particular error

Answer (score 1):

```
public void CreateScriptTable() 
{
    ServerConnection serverConnection = new ServerConnection(".");
    Server server = new Server(serverConnection);
    Database database = server.Databases["ff"];
    Table tb = database.Tables["t"];
    Scripter scripter = new Scripter(server);
    scripter.Options.ScriptData = true;
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (string s in scripter.EnumScript(new Urn[] { tb.Urn }))
    sb.Append(s);

    System.IO.StreamWriter fs = System.IO.File.CreateText(@"ScriptTable");
    fs.Write(sb);
    fs.Close();
}
```