# Get Sql server's data using smo

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, smo

I'm using Sql Server Smo to create the scheme of database by C# application. However, I need a bit more, I also need to get data from each table as a **script** like below:

```
--........................................
INSERT INTO Table123 (...) VALUES (....)
INSERT INTO Table456 (...) VALUES (....)
--........................................
```

How can I do that and is it possible? Notice please that I need to create exactly a script using smo and not *.bak of a database, etc.

Comment: Why not using Entity Framework code first approach instate of `smo`? It creates database schema too. you can also generate sql scripts for insert/update/delete manually. check [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14528/Generate-SQL-INSERT-commands-programmatically)

Comment: SQL Server, so far as I'm aware, has no facility to dump its data in the form of an `INSERT` script. You can use BCP to produce e.g. csv files and a format file, but it would not fit the format of what you're asking for.

Comment: If you are building up the schema why can't you just build up that script as text.

Comment: Well, it is possible to combine SMO to enumerate tables/columns/whatever to get the DDL, and use classic querying to build string script, since Smo.Scripter won't create DML.

Comment: Turns out Smo.Scripter _will_ generate DML if you use the ScriptData = true option and the Scripter.EnumScript method. At least it did for me (see sample in my answer).

Comment: @Joseph Sturtevant: Well, I remember I was looking for that back in 2005 days, but haven't found anything useful. I'll surely have a look at this!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Have a look at SMO's [Scripter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scripter.aspx) class. The following basic sample works for me:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

namespace SqlExporter
{
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var server = new Server(new ServerConnection {ConnectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder {DataSource = @"LOCALHOST\SQLEXPRESS", IntegratedSecurity = true}.ToString()});
    server.ConnectionContext.Connect();
    var database = server.Databases["MyDatabase"];
    var output = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (Table table in database.Tables)
    {
        var scripter = new Scripter(server) {Options = {ScriptData = true}};
        var script = scripter.EnumScript(new SqlSmoObject[] {table});
        foreach (var line in script)
            output.AppendLine(line);
    }
    File.WriteAllText(@"D:\MyDatabase.sql", output.ToString());
}
}
}
```

**Note:** This example doesn't handle any foreign key constraints or other dependencies between tables.

**References:**

1. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365408/c-sharp-smo-scripting-table-data-to-file-throwing-error) (that turned me onto the [Scripter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scripter.aspx) class)
2. [This MSDN forum question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlsmoanddmo/thread/f456a535-f7c1-49f7-90f4-6a8bf251fd3b) (that explained how to use the [EnumScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc285610.aspx) method)

Comment: Is there are way to script just a part of the data of a table? (Expressing a where condition)

Comment: I am also trying to do this , i.e. Expressing a where condition, does anyone know if this is possible with SMO?

Comment: for data only use:
`var scripter = new Scripter(server) { Options = { ScriptData = true, ScriptSchema=false } };`