# Export sql server table structure with data programmatically using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table with data in sql server. I need to take the backup of that table structure as well as data into some sort of file programmatically using `C#`. May be `.sql` extension file. Same way as we do using `Task` option in sql server management studio.

I googled it but did not find anything related to this. If anybody suggest me any link will be highly appreciated.

---

(Edited in from comments)

The backup is for safety purpose. As I am going execute the conversion logic for one of my scheduler control. The process is:

1. Get the backup of the table data into a list.
2. Truncate the table.
3. Convert the data to desired format.
4. Insert the converted data into the same table.

If any conversion logic problem, I can fix it later using the backup file.

Comment: Just that table, or the whole database?

Comment: @Paddy, Just a single table structure and its data.

Comment: And what will the purpose of this backup be?

Comment: Consider using SMOs(Server Management Objects). It was designed for this sort of thing. Here is an intro http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/97863/What-are-the-SQL-Server-Management-Objects. Using it you can programatically access every structure in the sql server(databases, tables, views, triggers...along with their data). You can also do backups...

Comment: @Paddy, The backup is for safety purpose. As I am going execute the conversion logic for one of my scheduler control. The process is -> Get the backup of the table data into a list  -> truncate the table -> Convert the data to desired format -> Insert the converted data into the same table.

If any conversion logic problem, I can fix it later using the backup file.

Comment: Would it not make more sense to backup into another (appropriately named table)? This was rollbacks are much easier to implement rather than having to script something back in.  Also very easy to implement.

Comment: OP Said:"*I do not have access to create the table in server db. So, I want the backup data to be in form of file.*" I addressed that in my answer below how he can backup data to a XML file. So please explain to me why downvote?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233982/get-sql-servers-data-using-smo

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
select * into newtable from yourtable
```

you do not need to create `newtable`  manually, just execute the query.

**Update**:You can download your Database data to dataset and use dataset to write xml with or without schema using [`DataSet.WriteXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hb27k0tf.aspx) method like this:

```
ds.WriteXml(@"E:\Temp.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```