# Use SMO to iterate through all the data in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I need to do a tool to traverse SQL Server, need to export all the tables into text. This is the first time I use C # and SMO, encountered a very simple question. I traverse all the columns of all the table , But do not know how to get the data from the column, thanks to know the guidance of friends, thank you!

In addition, my English level is very general, these words are translated through the translation software, so if the grammar is a problem, I am sorry, regret not in school to learn English ...

```
public void EnumDB()
    {
        foreach (Database db in srv.Databases)//Traverse the database in the instance
        {
            Console.WriteLine(db.Name);//Print the database name

            foreach (Table table in db.Tables)//Traverse the tables in the database
            {
                Console.WriteLine(table.Name);//Print the table name

                foreach (Column col in table.Columns)//Traverse the columns in the table
                {
                    //How to get the data in the column？tks!!
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation?  Surely there must be something there!

Comment: You have to do a query. Those objects have no notion of the data.

Comment: I checked the SMO documentation, did not find and get the data related ...

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233982/get-sql-servers-data-using-smo

Comment: The above link, like enumeration sql script, I need to enumerate the data in each line of the table, in the form of text preservation. This is my first use of C # and SMO, is the first time to do database related Of the operation, because it is very urgent, so I would like to make the first tool to go after the detailed study of the database to learn the relevant knowledge, but still very grateful to the above several friends, thank you !!

Comment: Let me ask you this: what are you planning on *doing* with the text once you have extracted it? If your goal is preservation, a simple database backup will almost assuredly do a better job than extracting every table to a file.

Comment: My purpose is not to save and backup the database, but in order to extract the database table, save to the text file, there is a need to use the text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to find a lot of ways, but did not find the way to get SQL server database content through SMO. Perhaps SMO is more suitable for managing databases, such as restore and backup. If you need to get the database content, it is recommended to use ADO / ADO.net, No, but you can learn quickly.