# Script Data Dynamically using TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I came up with the following script to dynamically create INSERT statements for a given table.

```
CREATE TABLE Employee ([Id] int, [Name] NVARCHAR(25))
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (1, 'Vyas')
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (2, 'Nandhini')


select 'Insert into employee (' +
STUFF ((
        SELECT ', [' + name + ']'
        FROM syscolumns
        WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('employee')
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') +
') values(' +
stuff((select +',' + cast([id] as varchar(2)) +','''+ [name] + '''' from Employee e1 where e1.id = e2.id  for xml path('')),1,1,'') +
')'
from employee e2
```

The script creates insert statements as required.

```
Insert into employee ( [Id], [Name]) values(1,'Vyas')
Insert into employee ( [Id], [Name]) values(2,'Nandhini')
```

However, I need

1. The value SQL statement to be dynamic as the first
2. Only selected columns with common SQL Server datatypes to be handled & quoted correctly (int, [n]varchar, uniqueidentifier and bit)

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Pretty much just like you are doing, just extended to handle all datatypes.

Comment: I usually do the same concept except in Excel.

Comment: You can use SMO to create scripts that include data as INSERT statements. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233982/get-sql-servers-data-using-smo

Comment: If you want to quote your values properly (and they are less than 129 characters) use `QUOTENAME`. Note, as well, that `'...''' + SomeVarchar + '''...'` would result in the loss of characters out side of the codepage of the database's collation for `varchar`s, as it would only wrap the value in single quotes, and there would be no `N` notation character.

Comment: Why would you want to do this out of curiosity?

Comment: Just to clarify, by "ALL" types you mean to include `varbinary(max)`, `xml`, `sql_variant`, `geometry`, `geography`, `hierarchyid` and user defined types, correct? How about [`rowversion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)? Do you need to support [`boolean`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comparison-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#boolean-data-type), even if it can't be a column data type?

Comment: @HABO:  Great question.  I clarified the same.  Need only common data types.

Comment: Just to clarify the clarification, while [`boolean`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comparison-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#boolean-data-type) is a "common data type", it isn't a valid data type for a column. Do you mean [`bit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: @HABO: Yes.  Corrected the question as well.

Comment: Practical solution: find someone who has already done it, tested it and shared it, and use theirs.